# Retrieve Text From ASCII In Matlab

Tags: matlab, cryptography

I have the following lines of code :

```
%for RSA Algorithm
clc;

disp('Implementation of RSA Algorithm');

clear all; 
close all;

p = input('\nEnter value of p: ');
q = input('\nEnter value of q: ');

[Pk,Phi,d,e] = init(p,q);

M = input('\nEnter message: ','s');
x=length(M);
c=0;

for j= 1:x
    for i=0:122
        if strcmp(M(j),char(i))
            c(j)=i;
        end
    end
end

disp('ASCII Code of the entered Message:');
disp(c); 
% For Encryption
for j= 1:x
   cipher(j)= crypto(c(j),Pk,e); 
end

disp('Cipher Text of the entered Message:');
disp(cipher);
```

How can I know the text of encrypted message ? I mean what are the characters of the encryption ? I want the ASCII code of `cipher` to be converted back into characters. Can someone tell me the matlab code for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Modular exponentiation - the main mathematical primitive used for RSA encryption/decryption uses *integer values* as input and output. The RSA algorithms themselves (in [PKCS#1 v2.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2437.txt) onwards) first convert messages to octets, then pads these objects according to one of two padding schemes, then perform modular exponentiation on the result converted to integer. The resulting integer in turn is converted to octets again.

Now depending on the actually performed calculation described above, you should have either an integer or octets. As it is not hard to convert an integer to octets - or to print an integer - lets focus only on octets. You need to create a string (text) from something that is inherently not text. There are specific encoding schemes that do this, but the most common one is [base 64](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/matlab/software/util/datautil/).

Note that usually you only perform one RSA encryption per plaintext. If the plaintext does not fit (or may not fit in the future, or if you just want to adhere to standards) then you should use [hybrid encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) instead of RSA ["in ECB mode"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29).

Comment: For just validating your results, I would use hexadecimals over base 64 by the way.